# Flink common state for all keys in the KeyedProcessFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to keep a simple value for all states in the `KeyedProcessFunction` like below;

```
class StateC() extends KeyedProcessFunction[Long, A, B] {
  var timestamp: Timestamp = _

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    timestamp = assignCurrentHour()
  }

 override def processElement(item: A, ... ): Unit = {
    val currentHour = now.truncateToHour()
    if (currentHour.after(timestamp)) { 
      timestamp = assignCurrentHour()
    }
   .... 
 }
}
```

I just want to find that am i in the new hour or not. For that i keep `timestamp` variable.The value of the `timestamp` variable is common for all keys in this TaskManager. So I do not need to state for each key.

In this case, `timestamp` variable will be updated when any event processed by this `task manager` in the new hour, right?

Could it be concurrent modification on the `timestamp` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation you proposed looks fine (but keep in mind I'm not aware of all of your requirements). Each parallel instance of the `KeyedProcessFunction` will have its own version of the timestamp, and each will update its timestamp as soon as an event is processed in the new hour. A `KeyedProcessFunction` is single threaded: you don't have to worry about concurrent updates. (The `onTimer` method is synchronized with the others; there's nothing to worry about there.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Broadcast State which is common state for all task

Detailed usage can refer to
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/

public abstract class KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction<KS, IN1, IN2, OUT>
extends BaseBroadcastProcessFunction {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2584726797564976453L;

/**
 * This method is called for each element in the (non-broadcast) {@link
 * org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.KeyedStream keyed stream}.
 *
 * <p>It can output zero or more elements using the {@link Collector} parameter, query the
 * current processing/event time, and also query and update the local keyed state. In addition,
 * it can get a {@link TimerService} for registering timers and querying the time. Finally, it
 * has <b>read-only</b> access to the broadcast state. The context is only valid during the
 * invocation of this method, do not store it.
 *
 * @param value The stream element.
 * @param ctx A {@link ReadOnlyContext} that allows querying the timestamp of the element,
 *     querying the current processing/event time and iterating the broadcast state with
 *     <b>read-only</b> access. The context is only valid during the invocation of this method,
 *     do not store it.
 * @param out The collector to emit resulting elements to
 * @throws Exception The function may throw exceptions which cause the streaming program to fail
 *     and go into recovery.
 */
public abstract void processElement(
        final IN1 value, final ReadOnlyContext ctx, final Collector<OUT> out) throws Exception;

/**
 * This method is called for each element in the {@link
 * org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.BroadcastStream broadcast stream}.
 *
 * <p>It can output zero or more elements using the {@link Collector} parameter, query the
 * current processing/event time, and also query and update the internal {@link
 * org.apache.flink.api.common.state.BroadcastState broadcast state}. In addition, it can
 * register a {@link KeyedStateFunction function} to be applied to all keyed states on the local
 * partition. These can be done through the provided {@link Context}. The context is only valid
 * during the invocation of this method, do not store it.
 *
 * @param value The stream element.
 * @param ctx A {@link Context} that allows querying the timestamp of the element, querying the
 *     current processing/event time and updating the broadcast state. In addition, it allows
 *     the registration of a {@link KeyedStateFunction function} to be applied to all keyed
 *     state with a given {@link StateDescriptor} on the local partition. The context is only
 *     valid during the invocation of this method, do not store it.
 * @param out The collector to emit resulting elements to
 * @throws Exception The function may throw exceptions which cause the streaming program to fail
 *     and go into recovery.
 */
public abstract void processBroadcastElement(
        final IN2 value, final Context ctx, final Collector<OUT> out) throws Exception;
```

Comment: I'm not sure, this is a bit complicated. I just want to learn that my solution is work or not. If not, yes i can try your solution